# wrong list.sort() with numbers with dots (decimals)

Tags: list, sorting, decimal

I am trying to sort a list of numbers, the list looks similar to:

```
['8.5444777260000002', 
'8.9833287639999995', 
'7.6962368249999997', 
'1.3958622080000000', 
'0.0000000000000000', 
'0.0000000000000000', 
'12.6939330199999993', 
'12.6858463900000000', 
'9.0969571279999997']
```

although it has many more elements.

My problem is that when I sort this list, the first number is `0.000000000000`
but the last number of the list is `9.something`

While I know there are numbers above the 9 value. Then when I review the sorted list I observed that after the `0.9999999999` the `10.0000000000` was placed and then all the numbers from 10 to 20 before showing the `2.0000000000`

Any idea why this is happening? Any advice or suggestion about what is wrong?

Comment: Yes. You're sorting as text. Sort as numbers instead.

Comment: Post your code/command.

Comment: @KenWhite: the elements in my list look like strings but act as floats in fact, when I ask ie. for one element on my list if it is bigger or smaller than 5 it works as a float...

Comment: The elements in your list *are* strings, because floats are not surrounded by quotes. The sort you describe is an ASCII (alpha sort), not a numeric sort.

Comment: What programming language is this? Please add a proper tag to your question, so people will know.

Comment: This is Python what I am programming with. @KenWhite The list comes from a numpy array and they are numpy.float64, I tried to change them to python scalars with a map. but apparently they are the same. I am new in Python and it was the first time I started used np.array.

Comment: OK. I did again the map. to change to float and I succeeded. Thanks for the fast and quick answers.